# Python3 Fast Way To Check If Element In Collection Of Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

In `Python3`, is there a faster method to check if your element exists in a collection of elements than doing a try except with a dictionary?

I timed the following and try except was very fast compared to looping through an array, is there a better way to go about doing this without using `try`/`except`?

```
import timing

bad_extensions_array = ['.png', '.gif',
                '.map', '.jpg', '.ico', '.gzip', '.idx',
                '.pack', '.eot', '.ttf', '.woff', '.zip',
                '.pfx', '.woff2', '.o', '.node', '.gz',
                '.icns', '.tgz', '.dll', '.js', '.nib',
                '.PNG', '.exe', '.strings', '.xlsx', '.xls',
                '.phar', '.xcf', '.foo', '.bmp', '.ser',
                '.otf', '.gnumeric', '.ods', '.xml', '.graffle',
                '.pdf']

bad_extensions_dict = {
    '.png':True, '.gif':True,
    '.map':True, '.jpg':True, '.ico':True, '.gzip':True, '.idx':True,
    '.pack':True, '.eot':True, '.ttf':True, '.woff':True, '.zip':True,
    '.pfx':True, '.woff2':True, '.o':True, '.node':True, '.gz':True,
    '.icns':True, '.tgz':True, '.dll':True, '.js':True, '.nib':True,
    '.PNG':True, '.exe':True, '.strings':True, '.xlsx':True, '.xls':True,
    '.phar':True, '.xcf':True, '.foo':True, '.bmp':True, '.ser':True,
    '.otf':True, '.gnumeric':True, '.ods':True, '.xml':True, '.graffle':True,
    '.pdf':True
}

ext_ = 'sdsd'

# ext_ not found
# 0:00:00.110999

# ext_ first in array
# 0:00:00.018037

def check_list():
    if ext_ in bad_extensions_array:
        return True
    return False

# ext_ not found
# 0:00:00.043047

# ext_ found
# 0:00:00.018655

def check_dict():
    try:
        return bad_extensions_dict[ext_]
    except:
        return False

for x in range(100000):
    #check_list()
    #check_dict
```

Comment: `in` also works on dictionaries. But consider using a set if you only care about keys and not values.

Comment: you could use `.get(ext_,False)` to return False if the key is not present, although I'm not sure if it is any faster

Comment: nope `dict.get` is consistently slower but `in` works just as well on `dict` then on `set` (both much faster then `list`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Kevin, `in` also works on dictionaries. It actually works on any standard collection (albeit with a slightly different definition on `str`).

When checking against a dictionary, you're identifying whether that key exists.

As also stated, if `bad_extensions` only represents extensions you are not supposed to use, a set would be best, as such:

```
bad_extensions = {
    'bmp', 'dll', 'eot', 'exe', 'foo', 'gif', 'gnumeric', 'graffle', 'gz',
    'gzip', 'icns', 'ico', 'idx', 'jpg', 'js', 'map', 'nib', 'node', 'o',
    'ods', 'otf', 'pack', 'pdf', 'pfx', 'phar', 'png', 'ser', 'strings',
    'tgz', 'ttf', 'woff', 'woff2', 'xcf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'xml', 'zip'
}
```

Comment: wow, using `in` with the set was 60X faster than the try except dict

Comment: @ClickThisNick I've noticed you've also got some values in your set which differ only by case. Consider having every item in `bad_extensions` be lower case and check with `extension.lower() in bad_extensions`.

Comment: Tested out the case and the .lower made it almost twice as slow, Im trading speed for accuracy in this scenario. Also I don't need to be checking the `.` in the extension. That will make it a *bit* faster as well

Comment: @ClickThisNick I've reformatted `bad_extensions` to be sorted and omit the period.

Comment: Awesome this really flys now. Just wondering, does the order of the set matter?

Comment: @ClickThisNick Sets are, by definition, unordered. So, no.